# System of n homogeneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $z_0, z_1,\ldots, z_{n-1}$ are the $n$ distinct solutions of $z^n=1$

Consider the system of $n$ homogeneous equations in the $n$ unknowns $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ given by: 
$$
x_0+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}=0 \\
z_0x_0+z_1x_1+\cdots+z_{n-1}x_{n-1}=0\\ 
z_0^2x_0^2+z_1^2x_1^2+\cdots z_{n-1}^2x_{n-1}^2=0 \\
\vdots \\
z_0^{n-1}x_0+z_1^{n-1}x_1+z_2^{n-1}x_2+\cdots+z_{n-1}^{n-1}x_{n-1}=0
$$
Show that the only solution to this system of equations is $x_0=x_1=\cdots=x_{n-1}=0$.

So far this is what I have:

If $j$ doesn't equal $k$ then $\frac{z_j}{z_k}$ doesn't equal $1$, so to show that $x_k=0$, I need to write each equation as an equation whose coefficient of $x_k$ is $1$ and add the equations together. So after I set each $x_k$ to $1$ and solve it like a regular system of equations, correct?

Comment: This is nigh-unreadable, you're more likely to get replies if you spend a few minutes formatting your equations with TeX.

Comment: I TeX-ified your problem. Can you read through it, and check that there are no mistakes?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was in a hurry before work this morning.  I appreciate you doing that and it looks great the way you TeX-ified it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of this system is the Vandermonde Determinant $V_n^T$ where  $$V_n = \begin{vmatrix}
  1 & z_0 & z_0^2 & \cdots & z_0^{n-2} & z_0^{n-1} \\
  1 & z_1 & z_1^2 & \cdots & z_1^{n-2} & z_1^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & z_{n-1} & z_{n-1}^2 & \cdots & z_{n-1}^{n-2} & z_{n-1}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix} =\prod_{0 \mathop \le i \mathop < j \mathop \le n-1} \left({z_j - z_i}\right)\neq 0$$
and therefore the system has only zero as solution.

Answer (score 1):

The uniqueness of the solution is equivalent to the n by n coefficient martix being invertible. The coefficient matrix is Vandermonde matrix and has the formula given http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix. All $z_i$ are distinct therefore the determinant is non zero and the matrix is invertible.